# Is a spell lattice a "weapon-like object" for the purposes of drawing and sheathing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, actions

The [combat page](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Move-Actions) at d20pfsrd.com describes the Pathfinder rules for drawing and sheathing a weapon, and then states: "This action also applies to weapon-like objects carried in easy reach, such as wands."

Is a [spell lattice](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/spell-lattice/) considered a weapon-like object, in addition to wands?

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out the action economy for using a spell lattice, which requires being held to use.  Ideally the character could have a belt pouch of lattices, and grab one while moving.

Comment: I focused this on spell lattices, because that seems to be your real aim here, and it’s a much more answerable question. If such a list exists (I strongly doubt it does), someone might answer by pointing it out and whether or not spell lattices are on it. But this way, even if the list doesn’t exist (and again, it probably does not), possibly an answer might be able to find something specific about spell lattices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific rules that defines spell lattices as a weapon-like object.  It would fall under the general "Retrieving an item" rule unless your GM states otherwise.

However, you might have better chances with a Spring-loaded Wrist Sheath.

Comment: As pathfinder gives such little guidance on what is a weapon-like object, this is probably the best answer we'll get.